# Informix stored procedure generic exception handling

Tags: exception, stored-procedures, informix

I am trying to create a stored procedure in Informix.
I want to handle all exceptions that occur while inserting a row in a table

I came across

> ON EXCEPTION IN (error code) insert statement END EXCEPTION

which is used to handle a specific exception(error code).

My question is "how can I handle all generic exceptions in Informix"?

In Oracle, I have used "EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS then" statement; what is the Informix equivalent to the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the online  [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1351.htm) , you just do not define the `IN` clause.

> The ON EXCEPTION statement, together with the RAISE EXCEPTION
>   statement, provides an error-trapping and error-recovery mechanism for
>   SPL routines. ON EXCEPTION can specify the errors that you want to
>   trap as the SPL routine executes, and specifies the action to take if
>   the error occurs within the statement block. The ON EXCEPTION
>   statement can list one or more specific error numbers in the IN
>   clause, **or it can trap all errors (or any error) if the IN clause is
>   omitted**.

Comment: It's in there, but they bury it. I read the documentation and still ended up here. Thank you!